# selecting a fixed dataframe range based upon index and appending to a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
resultsDf
```

Which returns the following:

```
       0
0     100
1   -2800
2   -2800
3   -2800
0   -2800
1   -2800
2   -2900
3   -3000
0   -3000
1   -3000
2   -3000
3   -3000
0   -3000
1   -3000
2   -3000
3   -3000
.  
.  
.   
0  -3100
1  25500
```

I would like to extract a fixed subset of the dataframe based upon the index, which is 0,1,2,3

I would then like to add each frame to a new dataframe in a column format.  So the end dataframe should look like:

```
  C1   C2   C3.....Cn
0
1
2
3
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concatenate rows column-wise in Python Pandas with groupby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34634197/concatenate-rows-column-wise-in-python-pandas-with-groupby)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert df to numpy array by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) and [`reshape`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html). then you can set new columns names by list comprehension with [range](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range):

```
print resultsDf

      0
0   100
1 -2800
2 -2800
3 -2800
0 -2800
1 -2800
2 -2900
3 -3000
0 -3000
1 -3000
2 -3000
3 -3000
0 -3000
1 -3000
2 -3000
3 -3000

df = pd.DataFrame((resultsDf.values).reshape((4, (resultsDf.values).shape[0]/4)))
df.columns = ['C' + str(i) for i in range(1, len(df.columns) + 1) ]

print df

     C1    C2    C3    C4
0   100 -2800 -2800 -2800
1 -2800 -2800 -2900 -3000
2 -3000 -3000 -3000 -3000
3 -3000 -3000 -3000 -3000
```

If you have last rows missing (not repeating indices as other rows):

```
print resultsDf

        0
0     100
1   -2800
2   -2800
3   -2800
4   -2800
5   -2800
6   -2900
7   -3000
8   -3000
9   -3000
10  -3000
11  -3000
12  -3000
13  -3000
14  -3000
15  -3000
0     100
1   -2800
2   -2800
3   -2800
4   -2800
5   -2800
6   -2900
7   -3000
8   -3000
9   -3000
10  -3000
11  -3000
12  -3000
13  -3000
14  -3000
15  -3000
0   -3100
1   25500
```

```
#use all df without last two rows - resultsDf[:-2]
df = pd.DataFrame((resultsDf[:-2].values).reshape(16, resultsDf[:-2].values.shape[0]/16))
#append last two rows to new df
df = pd.concat([df, resultsDf[-2:]], axis=1)
df.columns = ['C' + str(i) for i in range(1, len(df.columns) + 1) ]

print df

      C1    C2     C3
0    100 -2800  -3100
1  -2800 -2800  25500
2  -2800 -2800    NaN
3  -2900 -3000    NaN
4  -3000 -3000    NaN
5  -3000 -3000    NaN
6  -3000 -3000    NaN
7  -3000 -3000    NaN
8    100 -2800    NaN
9  -2800 -2800    NaN
10 -2800 -2800    NaN
11 -2900 -3000    NaN
12 -3000 -3000    NaN
13 -3000 -3000    NaN
14 -3000 -3000    NaN
15 -3000 -3000    NaN
```

Comment: print (resultsDf.values).shape returns (34,1)

Comment: @jezreal The data is not secretive but is in fact very large.  The values I have posted are indicative of the data.

Comment: @jezreal - just to add there are no values missing.  The index is from 0 to 16.

Comment: @jezreal the shape of the real data is (34,1)  All results of the index repeat from 0 to 16.  All elements in the vector have a value.

Comment: Thanks for all your help!