# How can I merge rows using alternative columns as key?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a data set composed of some tweets. Each tweet sits in one row. I want to merge the tweets that belong to the same "conversation" together. I identify which tweets belong to a particular conversation by matching the `tweet_ID` values with `reply_to_ID` values. Basically, when the `reply_to_ID` of one tweet matches `tweet_ID` of another, it means the former tweet is a reply to the latter. Below is an example:

```
tweet_ID   reply_to_ID
1          None
2          1
3          1
4          3
5          None
6          4
7          5
8          None
9          5
```

the result should look like this

```
1      |None   |2      |1      |3      |1      |4      |3      |6      |4      |
5      |None   |7      |5      |9      |5      
8      |None
```

In this example `tweet_ID = 1` gets two "direct" replies: `tweet_ID = 2, 3` and two "indirect" replies: `tweet_ID = 4, 6`, which are replies to `tweet_ID = 3` and `tweet_ID = 4` but are considered indirect reply to `tweet_ID = 1` since `tweet_ID = 3` is itself a reply to `tweet_ID =1` and `tweet_ID = 6` is a reply to `tweet_ID =4`, which is an indirect reply to `tweet_ID =1`. We don't know how deep this rabbit hole goes. In other words, we don't know how many indirect replies there are for a given tweet.

`tweet_ID = 5` has two direct replies and no indirect replies, and `tweet_ID = 8` has neither direct nor indirect replies.

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61674383/how-to-concatenate-rows-with-the-same-column-value-in-python/61691472#61691472) has a code that can be used to extract "direct" replies, but what should we do in case of indirect replies, where the key in merge keeps alternating between two columns?

Comment: What have you tried? Can u post your code?

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution for your question, you can adapt for your real problem.

```
 tweets = [[1, None],
          [2, 1],
          [3, 1],
          [4, 3],
          [5, None],
          [6, 4],
          [7, 5],
          [8, None],
          [9, 5]]


def create_tweets_path(tweet_list: list):
    new_paths = []
    for idx, elem in enumerate(tweet_list):
        if elem[1] is None:
            result = create_new_path(tweet_list[idx:])
            new_paths.append(result)

    return new_paths


def create_new_path(tweet_list: list):
    new_list = [tweet_list[0][0]]
    new_real_list = [tweet_list[0]]
    for elem in tweet_list:
        if elem[1] in new_list:
            new_list.append(elem[0])
            new_real_list.append(elem)
    return new_real_list


paths = create_tweets_path(tweet_list=tweets)

for line in paths:
    print(line)

##Output##
[[1, None], [2, 1], [3, 1], [4, 3], [6, 4]]
[[5, None], [7, 5], [9, 5]]
[[8, None]]
```

Comment: Updated for a more efficient way!

Comment: Updated again, is more efficient now!

Comment: this is not true. If the order of elements changes, the results are not valid anymore.  consider ``` tweets = [[4, 3],
          [5, None],
          [6, 4],
          [1, None],
          [2, 1],
          [3, 1],
          [7, 5],
          [8, None],
          [9, 5]]
``` which is basically the same list, but the results are different.

Comment: I supposed that the list was ordered by the tweet ID, it makes no sense in other order. When a tweet is made, it is appended to the list, right? So, the list will be ordered by tweet ID. 
Anyway, you can order the list before call this function

Comment: Tweet_ID s are infact strings. But, your solution is still very clever. thank you!

Comment: You can sort it anyway. you have to cast to int first, if you try to sort strings, it work well from 0 to 9, but "10" will be after "1" and not "9". So, this second doesn't seem a right solution